# Do Damage Bonuses Against Grineer work on Ghouls as well?

Tags: warframe

I've found a few mods that give you damage bonuses against certain factions like Infested or Grineer.  I haven't seen one for Ghouls, but since Ghouls are just undead Grineer (I think?) I'm wondering if mods such as *Smite Grineer* or *Bane of Grineer* also give me a damage bonus against Ghouls.

There's a ghoul event on right now and this would be mega-helpful but I don't want to spend the Endo/Credits to upgrade the mods to a useful level if it won't work.

[image: Bane of Grineer || +5% Damage to Grineer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ghouls do take additional damage from Bane of Grineer (although if you were super min/maxing it's not the most effective mod to use.)

Lore wise Ghouls are not undead Grineer but rather less well made clones of the Grineer. All Grineer are clones but the Ghouls are essentially made on the cheap cheap, made to die quickly and in number. This is also why they deal damage on death, they were designed with their blood hurting enemies in mind.